# Why bean with name throws error but bean without name does not when trying to inject bean with "request" scope in spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

In my application I am trying to inject `ExecutorService` bean in `Controller` using constructor base injection.

CustomConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class CustomConfig {

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = REQUEST_SCOPE)
    public ExecutorService getExecutorService() {
           return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }
}
```

MyController.java

```
@Controller
@HorizonteController
public class MarketPageController {

   ExecutorService executorService;
   public MyController(ExecutorService executorService) {
       this.executorService = executorService;
   }

    @RequiresHttps
    @RequestMapping(value = { "abc", "abcd" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getPage(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
        //some logic
    }
}
```

Above code works completely fine. But If I modified my bean and attach name to it, then at run time I am getting Exception saying `Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread`.

Config.java(modified)

```
@Configuration
public class CustomConfig {

    @Bean(name = "myExecutorService")
    @Scope(value = REQUEST_SCOPE)
    public ExecutorService getExecutorService() {
           return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }
}
```

MyController.java(modified)

```
@Controller
@HorizonteController
public class MarketPageController {

   ExecutorService executorService;
   public MyController(@Named("myExecutorService") ExecutorService executorService) {
       this.executorService = executorService;
   }

    @RequiresHttps
    @RequestMapping(value = { "abc", "abcd" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getPage(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
        //some logic
    }
}
```

If I run this code, I am getting following error;

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myExecutorService': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to create bean "myExecutorService". There is no active request for the current thread. This may be the result of an un-proxied bean inside of a singleton or from a thread in a threadpool without the required thread-local propagation. This situation is not currently supported.
```

Does anyone know why I am getting error if I attach name with bean(why it is working fine when there is no name attached with bean)?

And how can I resolve it(I want to add name to bean, and also wanted that my code correctly)?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis is your code run successfully after modification(attaching name to bean)? (added some more code snippet, hope that helps)

Comment: I run you code success(attaching name to bean).

Comment: No, the code fails in both cases. Are you applying proxying anywhere? We'll need a [mcve].

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No I haven't applied proxying anywhere. This is only peace of code which I have in my package. For me it is failing for one and not for other.(Let me check once again, there might be some hidden thing there which I am forgot mention here)